# What are these tower-like things outside Luke's home on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, object-identification

On Tatooine outside Luke's house, there are these small tower-like objects outside Luke's home. There are 3-4 of them.

[image]

The same thing can also be seen outside of Obi-Wan's house as well.

[image]

**What are these and their purpose?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Those are [moisture vaporators](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Moisture_vaporator). These are quite literally the entire point of the moisture farm, to collect atmospheric water vapor. According to the Star Wars: Official Fact Files, a single vaporator can collect 1.5 litres of water per day.

[image]

[image]
<sub><sup>[The Official Star Wars Fact File #8](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_8)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[The Official Star Wars Fact File #8](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_8)</sup></sub>

The one outside Ben's house (an abandoned moisture farmer's hut) is a *low output* vaporator, one suitable for a single house.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Wars: Inside the Worlds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars_Trilogy)</sup></sub>

Comment: Very similar to binary loadlifters in most respects.

Comment: @Tim my *first* job was programming binary load lifters!

Comment: 1.5 liters a day for a whole house? That's not even enough for a single person.

Comment: @DonyorM - I spotted that.  My thought was that since his home is an abandoned moisture farm, there's probaby more than one of those vaporators nearby.

Comment: looks a lot more complex than the dehumidifier in my basement. That will pull about a gallon of water a day.

Comment: @KevinMilner - Is your basement on a desert planet with two suns?

Comment: The name "vaporator" seems wrong (that would be doing the inverse stuff). Should be a "condensor", I think?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - Technically it's a dehumidifier. In spaaaaace!!!

Comment: @DonyorM apparently the exchange rate between water and blue milk is pretty good.

Comment: @DonyorM I think he lived on a moisture *farm*, meaning there were several of these towers spread out through a large swath of land. Sort of how a single patch of corn can't feed a family, but a large field can.

Comment: @user151841 the post says that the picture shows a "low output vaporator, one suitable for a single house." Implying that one is suitable for an entire house, which isn't very likely. (Unless I misread a post).

Comment: @DonyorM - The discontinuity here is in how much water they can produce. The Fact File has a very pessimistic view whereas the "inside the Worlds" book is more generous.

Comment: @DonyorM Don't forget that the 1.5 liters is how much you gain per day.  That doesn't include the amount that you reclaim from daily use.  I doubt that urine would be wasted away, for example.  If you assume <= 1.5 liters of daily water loss, rather than water use, the device would be enough to sustain the household.

Comment: @valorum during the summer its more like Dagobah. :(

Comment: @DonyorM It's blue liters. They are more hydrating.

Comment: So, someone in Luke's family goes around all these vaporators every day with a bucket? 15 liter bucket = 10 vaporators total water for 1 day.

Comment: @vikingsteve - I'm assuming that in the Star Wars galaxy they've invented pipes